# initializer_list for arrays with predefined sizes

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

So let's imagine we want to use c++'s initializer_list for some user-defined type that represents array of predefined size (know at compile time). For example matrix's indexes (row,column):

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <assert.h>

using idx_t = unsigned;

class MatrixIdx {
public:
    MatrixIdx() :
        _idx { 0, 0 }
    {}

    // this is how I'm able to use initializer list for now
    // cons:
    //     * run-time assertion
    //     * additional header (algorithm)
    //     * not in member initializer list (call me perfectionist)
    //
    MatrixIdx(std::initializer_list<idx_t> l)
    {
        assert(l.size() == 2);
        std::copy(l.begin(), l.end(), _idx);
    }

    //I want to achive constructor similiar to this one
    //Won't compile
    //
    //MatrixIdx(std::initializer_list<idx_t> l) :
        //static_assert(l.size() == 2, "two elements expected") //compile time assertion
        //_idx[0] ( l[0] ),
        //_idx[1] ( l[1] )
    //{}

    idx_t row() { return _idx[0]; }
    void setRow(const idx_t i) { _idx[0] = i; }

    idx_t col() { return _idx[1]; }
    void setCol(const idx_t i) { _idx[1] = i; }

private:
   idx_t _idx[2];
};

int main(void)
{
    MatrixIdx idx; //default - OKAY

    //MatrixIdx idxIL { 1, 2 }; //this should compile

    //this should emit human-readable compile-time error 
    //MatrixIdx idxILError { 1, 2, 3 };

    return 0;
}
```

What will be the best possible way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you require using `initializer_list`, or can it be something else that is initialized using braces?

Comment: it can be smth else using **curly** braces. Overall, I'm don't require anything, I'm just curios how one can implement smth similar to aforementioned class and keeping up with c++11 guideline of using **{}** (curly braces) for all type of initializations.

Comment: Uh, just give your class a constructor taking two `idx_t`s. It would be invoked just fine with `MatrixIdx idxIL { 1, 2 };` syntax. You are making it way too complicated.

Comment: You seem to think using `{braces, for, initialisation}` means/requires using `std::initializer_list`. It does not. The two are orthogonal concepts. That `{this, syntax}` happens to be called a _braced init-list_ is unfortunate but unrelated. A _braced init-list_ is implicitly deduced to an `std::initializer_list` in appropriate contexts, but it can just as easily be deduced to any other pack of separately typed arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Credit** should go to @IgorTandetnik, who provided the same answer as a comment of the OP.

---

The uniform initialization syntax can be adopted very simply for your situation, just by providing a constructor that accepts two arguments of type `idx_t`.

```
class MatrixIdx {
public:
  ...
  MatrixIdx() : ... {}
  MatrixIdx(idx_t, idx_t) : ... {}
};
```

And in your main code:

```
int main()
{
  MatrixIdx mat {}; // Okay
  MatrixIdx mat {1,2}; // Okay
  MatrixIdx mat {1,2,3}; // Error - no 3-arg. c'tor for MatrixIdx
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Also I think it would be fair to point out that *Igor Tandetnik* post a comment with the same info a bit earlier than you :). Anyway, now it's obvious to me that  my idea that **{}** means `std::initializer_list` was wrong.

Comment: Yes, @IgorTandetnik should claim credit for this.  Will adjust my post accordingly.